# Microsoft Access Update Query for One Record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to run an update query but I don't know how to update only the selected entry in the query subform.

Any pointers are appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Apply filter criteria with WHERE clause. Your question is too broad and there is no code for analysis. Why would you need to run an UPDATE action and not just do data entry/edit?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, there is no code just:
UPDATE [tabela Query] SET [tabela Query].analiza = Now()
WHERE [tabela Query].ID =

And I have no idea what to put after WHERE [tabela Query].ID = to point towards what I selected.

Thanks

Comment: Again, why run an UPDATE action when can just set value of field on form with code (macro or VBA)? Has data entry/edit of record on form already been initiated by user? If so, cannot also run an UPDATE action on that record because record is in edit mode. And exactly how are you causing that SQL to execute? Are you manually running query object from navigation pane? If you really must use query object, then must reference ID through subform container control: `Forms!mainformName!containerName!ID`. Should have provided that SQL in your question to begin with. Can edit question to improve.